# Getting "Instance of 'NotInitializedError'" in Flutter program

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, mobile-application

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as lat;
import 'package:location/location.dart' as loc;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

//besafe

 late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
LatLng getCurrentLatLngFromSharedPrefs() {
  return   LatLng(sharedPreferences.getDouble('latitude')!,
      sharedPreferences.getDouble('longitude')!);
}
void main() async{

  runApp(const MyApp());
  sharedPreferences =await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  const color2= Color(0xfb74093);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BeSafe',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'BeSafe'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

   late CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition;
   late MapboxMapController controller;


  static const List<String> imageList = [
    "https://www.uber-assets.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco,c_fill,w_1099,h_733/v1568070387/assets/b5/0a5191-836e-42bf-ad5d-6cb3100ec425/original/UberX.png",
    "https://www.uber-assets.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco,c_fill,w_956,h_537/v1569012661/assets/19/dea9bc-88d6-461e-a233-17ed4d8cdc09/original/Taxi.png",
    "https://www.uber-assets.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco,c_fill,w_956,h_537/v1571927853/assets/39/c1c2c7-61eb-4432-9bac-728b974207e7/original/cityscoot-icon-mobile.png"
  ];
   void initState(){
     super.initState();
     initializeLocationandSave();
     LatLng latlng= getCurrentLatLngFromSharedPrefs();
    _initialCameraPosition=CameraPosition(target:latlng  ,zoom:15);
    print("he");

   }
  void initializeLocationandSave() async{
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    loc.Location _location = loc.Location();
    bool? _serviceEnabled;
    loc.PermissionStatus? _permissionGranted;

    _serviceEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await _location.requestService();
    }

    _permissionGranted = await _location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == loc.PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await _location.requestPermission();
    }
    print("yo");
    loc.LocationData _locationData = await _location.getLocation();    print("bye");
    sharedPreferences.setDouble('latitude',_locationData.latitude!);
    sharedPreferences.setDouble('longitude',_locationData.latitude!);
    LatLng currentlatlng= getCurrentLatLngFromSharedPrefs();
  }
  _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) async {
    this.controller=controller;

  }
   _onStyleLoadedCallback() async{

   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
              MapboxMap(
                accessToken: dotenv.env['MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'] ,initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoadedCallback,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.TrackingGPS,
                minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(14, 17),
              ),
    new Positioned(
    child:SizedBox(
    height: 60,
    ),),
    new Positioned(
      child:
      Padding(
        padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:30,right:30,top:30),
        child:
        SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 10),
                ),
                fillColor: Colors.white24,
                filled: true,

              ),

            ))

      ),
    ),

          Padding(
            padding:EdgeInsets.only(top: 556),
            child: CarouselSlider(

              options: CarouselOptions(
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                height: 200,
                autoPlay: true,
              ),
              items: imageList.map((e) => ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(e,
                      width: 1050,
                      height: 300,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,)
                  ],
                ) ,
              )).toList(),

            ),
          ),



        ] ,


      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The program doesn't work and the error is NotIntialisedError which is confusing. I think it is something to do with the .getLocation() or the SharedPreferences variable.

I tried printing cout statements and apparently, the one line that  the code stops at is:

`loc.LocationData _locationData = await _location.getLocation();`

Error:

```
The following NotInitializedError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#9417a):
Instance of 'NotInitializedError'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MyHomePage MyHomePage:file:///C:/Users/ali33/StudioProjects/besafe/lib/main.dart:35:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
packages/flutter_dotenv/src/dotenv.dart 42:7                                                                               get env
packages/besafe/main.dart 113:40                                                                                           build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4919:27                                                                        build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4806:15                                                                        performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                                                        performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                                                         rebuild
```

Comment: Can you debug or print the value of sharedPrefrences and _location in the same line as the "yo" print?

Comment: Hey, I just did that, the output was "Instance of SharedPreferences" and "Instance of "Location"

Comment: Please share the full error message and stack trace. If you read it carefully, it may event explain the error to you.

Comment: you should not include access tokens in your posts. your token is now public for use by anyone. Try to reduce your code the minimum that still shows the error.

Comment: thank you, also, i just added as much of the error as stack overflow let me to my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in your main:

```
sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

has to be called before runApp, because it isn't initialized when you call this variable inside your widgets.

Switch it with   `runApp(const MyApp());`

Comment: unfortunately, same error :/

Comment: Did you debug? Which of the variables is null?